# IFileDialog: Can I use SetOptions after Show was called?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm using IFileSaveDialog in my application. So far everything works fine, but I need to set the options according to the filter. In my case I only need to set if the dialog works as a folder picker or as a file picker.

Setting the options before showing works, setting them after showing (while the dialog is visible and modal) an exception is thrown.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. The options must be set before the dialog is shown.

Comment: OK. Where did you read about this. I couldn't find anything in the documentation? So there is not way to change the behavior of the dialog during runtime?

Comment: I don't believe that this is documented. What behaviour do you want to change anyway? Not that it really matters since you can't do it anyway.

Comment: Alright. As described above. I have an export dialog. The filter distinguishes either by saving the data as a single file or into a directory. The solution of writing a file into a dialog as a dummy and then extract the file path is no option.

Comment: Yeah, you can't switch between file and directory picker once the dialog is shown.